# How to execute build_association if association is saved in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails `has_one` relationship, if the association name is stored in a string, how to build the child object whose name is saved in a string?

For example, a `customer` has_one `address`:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address
end
```

We can do:

```
customer = Customer.new
address = customer.build_address
```

If the association is saved in a variable name `@association`, How can we create `address` with the variable `@association`?:

```
@association = 'address'
customer = Customer.new
address = customer.build_{@association}  #code does not work.
```

We tried `customer.build_"#{@association}" & 'customer.build_#{@association}` and none of them worked.

Comment: Can I ask you why you are doing that while there is a simple possible way i.e, `address = customer.build_address`

Comment: `has_one` association is generated on the fly and saved in a string. We know there is something and don't know what exactly it is in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do meta-programming, ie here, calling a method whose name is contained in a variable.

The Ruby method you need to use is send :

```
customer.send("build_#{association_name}")
```

You can only use the `#{...}` syntax in double quoted strings `".."` OR regex `/../`

Note that send also work with symbols, and you can supply parameters after the first one. Remember that `=, [], !, ?` are also part of the method name.

```
method= 'name=', 
new_name= "hello"
@your_object.send(method, new_name)
```

Comment: Make sure you know what you are doing and it is sanitized if coming from a user input. Meta-programming is cool, but it's dangerous if not carefully thought.